Odoo ValidationError Not Displaying Pop-up During Record Update Nor During Create
I'm working on an Odoo model where I need to ensure that the allocated_hours field does not exceed 24 hours. I've implemented a constraint method to raise a ValidationError when the value exceeds 24 hours.
The validation works correctly, and the error message is displayed in the Odoo interface when navigating away from the view. However, when I update a record and the allocated_hours value exceeds 24, the error message is logged in the console, but the pop-up is not shown in the Odoo interface. And when creating a new record the method is not invoked at all.
Here's my code:
allocated_hours = fields.Integer('Estimation', compute='_compute_allocated_hours')

@api.constrains('allocated_hours')
def _check_allocated_hours(self):
    max_hours = 24.0  # Maximum allowed hours
    for record in self:
        if record.allocated_hours > max_hours:
            raise ValidationError("le max est 24h!!")


From odoo.api.constrains  documentation:

@constrains will be triggered only if the declared fields in the decorated method are included in the create or write call. It implies that fields not present in a view will not trigger a call during a record creation. An override of create is necessary to make sure a constraint will always be triggered (e.g. to test the absence of value).

You can see the following warning in the Odoo log:
WARNING ... @constrains parameter 'allocated_hours' is not writeable 

Try to add the constraint to the fields in the depend decorator of the compute method or raise the error from the compute method.

that worked thanks, it's trigered but i still have a problem the error message is showed in my console and noth the user interface

Did you import ValidationError?

yes of course, when i used to learn odoo i started with 15 , it worked there but know m using odoo 16 in my work and i faced this problem

Update the question with minimal code to reproduce the issue
